# How to dynamically get child components instead of using @ViewChild

Tags: angular

Basically instead of doing this:

```js
class Controller implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(IconComponent)
  iconComponent: IconComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    iconComponent.save();
  }

}
```

I would like to get a component like this:

```js
class Controller implements AfterViewInit{

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const iconComponent = someRef.get(IconComponent); // where to get this component from
    iconComponent.save()
  }

}
```

How do I achieve this?

I am asking this question because I get the component type in the runtime, not compiletime.

Comment: ViewChild can be use another selector than a Component or a class. use a variable reference "child" and  `ViewChild('child',{read:BaseClass}) myBaseComponent`

Comment: In annotation you have to know a component type in compiletime. I dont know its type there, so i need a solution which allows me to use a dynamic runtime type

Comment: If your component implements an interface (has functions and properties commons, I think -but I'm not sure- that you can use this Interface)

Comment: @Humberd How are the components used in the template? For example, are they placed inside the tags of the controller `<controller> <IconComp><IconComp></controller>`.  Is it possible to make sure that the components have a template ref placed on them e.g. `#target`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the component with the provided `ComponentFactoryResolver`?

By this way you can get its componentRef and manage its instance.

Here is the documentation of the [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) and you can find there a good implementation [example](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular).

Comment: Well, because this I don't want to manually create many components. I don't want to repeat @ViewChild and then invoking the same methods in that components. My components would inherit from a base class which would get this components and do the dirty stuff. Base class should not create components, because it doesn't know where to put them.

Comment: I see, maybe you can inject `ApplicationRef` and then access to its property `components` where you'll find all the registered components in the application. Don't resolve completly your problem...

Comment: Another issue with dynamicly created components is that Hot Module Reload doesn't reload them. It just leaves them hanging.

Comment: `ApplicationRef` doesn't help either. I would have to dig through a huge pile of components and it would be problematic to find the exact component I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can have an Injection Token. Even though types would cause you errors (hence typecast to any), this would work:

```
@ViewChild(YOUR_TOKEN as any)
component: YourAbstractClass;
```

Or, if you marked them all by some template reference variable:

```
@ViewChild('some', {read: YOUR_TOKEN})
component: YourAbstractClass;
```

All components derived from your abstract class should provide this token:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'your-component',
    templateUrl: './yourComponent.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./yourComponent.style.less'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: YOUR_TOKEN,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => YourComponent ),
        },
    ],
})
export class YourComponent extends YourAbstractClass {
```

This way you could also inject them all into directives.

Comment: Your solution requires knowing a type in compile time. I don't know the type. The type is passed as for example function argument.

Comment: Can you tell us some examples of `dirty stuff` that your base class would need to do? You can mark those components with template reference variable and make your base class generic and then child classes would give it the type. However I'm not sure what you can do with a generic in a base class. You would need to specify possible interfaces at least. Please give concrete examples, I'm sure we can think of something.